# How to edit/remove static blocks, cannot find anywhere

Tags: blocks, template, cms, magento-1, static-block

I have a lot of useless static blocks on my page that I would like to get rid of, the only thing is, I cannot find them in the normal CMS> Static Blocks or Configuration settings.

I would like to put more useful info in these boxes and get rid of some altogether.

Do I need to edit the template? if so, how and where do I find it?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because static content is added from files and those files are directly added in .phtml files.

Its also possible that content is added in current static block. ie we can edit new.phtml files to show some static content to display on home page. `This is not best practice but i saw many sites doing this and this is **STRONGLY not recommended**`

You should remove that types of content and add static block as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20948077/949003.

you can turn on template hint as told by @erfan.

```
System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Select a website or store view scope (current configuration scope) -> and turn on "Template path hints"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on template hints, refresh the frontend, and it will tell you which template file the content comes from.

You can turn on template hints in System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Select a website or store view scope (current configuration scope) -> and turn on "Template path hints"